# Slicing a Grid covered in Dominoes

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

How can I prove that no matter how one tiles a 6 x 6 rectangular grid with non-overlapping dominoes, the rectangular grid can be cut along a horizontal or vertical line without cutting one of the dominoes?

I've thought about using a coloring proof by coloring the grid like a chessboard, but I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: But wouldn't an answer to this be obvious? I mean if you can choose any horizontal line and any vertical line? Suppose you arrange them straight in each column, then there are 3 dominoes per column and 6 per row. In that case there are two horizontal lines and 5 vertical lines...

Answer (score 3):

Each domino crosses exactly one line. There are $18$ dominoes, and thus $18$ line crossings. Since there are $10$ lines, if all lines are crossed at least once, there are at least two lines that are crossed exactly once. But a line can't be crossed exactly once, since that would leave odd numbers of squares to be filled on either side.